Hyperplane section argument on Kähler manifold
On a projective variety, there exist very ample line bundles and hyperplane sections. It is a useful trick to take a general hyperplane section to reduce a problem to a lower dimension. However, on Kähler manifold, there is no hyperplane section.
My question is: Is there any (partial) analog (in any sense) of the 'hyperplane section argument' in Kähler geometry that can reduce the dimension?

On a very general compact complex torus, the only connected closed complex analytic subvarieties are points and the entire torus.

@JasonStarr That's true. So I'm expecting a completely different analog. For example,
something which is probably not a 'geometric submanifold'.

Maybe one can do something with foliations? But I can't off the top of my head think of any argument with hyperplane sections where a foliation would be sufficient.
